# How to get uiTableView cell index on didSelectItem of collectionView cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a tableView, which cell's contains collectionView. Now I want to get the tableview row index when I select any cell of collection view cell

Comment: you can set your tableViewCell indexPath.row as a tag for collectionView and get that tag in didSelectItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `cellForRowAt`

```
cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row
```

Comment: This does not take into account a tableview with multiple sections

Comment: in op question see "Now I want to get the tableview **row** index " he needs row not section which mean he has a table with 1 section

Answer (score 2):

Create a subclass of `UICollectionView` and add an attribute to it.

```
class MyCustomCollectionView: UICollectionView {
    var parentTableViewIndexPath: IndexPath?
}
```

Use this collection view in your tableview cell

```
class MyCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var customCollectionView: MyCustomCollectionView!
}
```

In your table's `cellForRow` method, set the indexPath attribute

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "IDENTIFIER", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomTableViewCell
    cell.customCollectionView.parentTableViewIndexPath = indexPath
    //Any additional customisation
    return cell
}
```

In your collectionView's `didSelectItemAt`, access the indexPath like this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let tableIndexPath = (collectionView as? MyCustomCollectionView)?.parentTableViewIndexPath else { return }
}
```